# Node.js + Passport: What happens to 3rd argument 'info' in done() method?

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I found that `done()` method (or `success()`, as told by my debugger) has a third argument as well which is called `info`. Can anybody tell me what happens to value passed into it?

**EDIT**

The `done()` method I am referring to is the one we have to call in a strategy callback. e.g.

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

The snippet is from [here](http://passportjs.org/guide/configure/). As it can be seen, in some cases, a `message` is being passed in an object as third argument to `done()`. How can we access this `message` in a route method?

Comment: Please show some example code or point us in the right direction. This is a bit vague. Also, I see you tagged it, but your question never mentions passport, so it took me a while to realize what you were asking about.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @loganfsmyth! I have updated the q, please let me know if it needs more explanation.

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the middleware?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to access the information passed as the third parameter as `req.authInfo`.

You can see the processing [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/6280d1f2dadab92fa3bd1095a3f1ee2c80fc698c/lib/authenticator.js#L361) as `info`, where it is assigned to `authInfo` and used for flash messages.

Answer (score 5):

`info` is an optional argument that can contain additional user information, such as roles, user profile, or authorization, that may have been determined during the verification function.
This helps with third-party authentication strategies, as these details about an authenticated user can be passed along once the user is successfully authenticated.  Otherwise, you might have to look them up a second time later one, which is inefficient.

And as [loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth) pointed out, `info` is set at `req.authInfo` so that middlware or routes can access it later on.

Additionally, you can transform the info object futher by [registering the transformAuthInfo](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/master/lib/passport/index.js#L330), like this:

```
passport.transformAuthInfo(function(info, done) {
  Client.findById(info.clientID, function (err, client) {
    info.client = client;
    done(err, info);
  });
});
```

For LocalStrategy, you can [see in the verified function](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/lib/passport-local/strategy.js#L80) that info gets passed to both fail and success actions.

So additionally, you can specify a `type` and a `message` properties and these will be used in flash status information messages displayed to the user. (`type` defaults to 'success' when user is authenticated, and 'error' otherwise).

Flash messages work in Express 2.x via the request.flash() function.
This was removed in Express 3.x - [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash) middleware is recommended if you need this functionality.